# How to run a custom task in Cygwin shell with VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin, aem, vscode-tasks

I am trying to set my development environment for an AEM project in **VSCode**.
I want to create various tasks to automate the syncing, fot that I need to use [repo](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/tools/tree/master/repo#integration-into-visual-studio-code), which only works in the cygwin shell.

The example in the repo documentation for the task definition is the following, but it's thought for mac.

```
{
  "label": "put file",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "repo put -f ${file}",
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

This is what I've been trying, it initializes the cygwin shell but doesn't seem to execute the command and it doesn't finish the task.

```
{
  "label": "put file",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "repo put -f ${file}",
  "options": {
      "shell": {
          "executable": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
          "args": ["/bin/xhere", "/bin/bash"]
       }
   },
   "problemMatcher": []
}
```

[The output of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P6Jd.png)

Can somebody help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are pushing AEM files to the remote repo and vice versa.

For that you can use other plugins too. As the above answer by Sharath, there are many alternatives.

One is **"aemsync"**. After installing this on your machine, you just have to run the command "**aemsync**" with or without paramters based on your requirements.

You can install aemsync using nodejs like this:

`npm install aemsync -g`

> You can visit here for a detailed documentation.
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/aemsync

There are multiple other ways to push your code, but this is a simple method. Also gulp-slang can be used.

**If you want to refer more simplified methods to sync aem, you can refer this.**

> https://hashouttech.com/simplify-your-aem-coding-with-vault-syncing-between-disk-and-server/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sync front end files to your AEM instance there are other alternatives in the node ecosystem that accomplish this.

You can try [gulp-slang](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-slang), it's a gulp watch task that pushes the changes into AEM as the files change.

and [aem-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aem-packager) to package content

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue, I was trying to run a task of `type: typescript` but I noticed the Cygwin shell `bash` couldn't process the Windows path, thus leading to `command not found` errors.

My solution was to use PowerShell to run the task, and this still gave desired results!

```json
{
  "type": "typescript",
  "options": {
      "shell": {
          "executable": "powershell.exe"
       }
   }
}
```